# Closing popup if user doesn't provide any response

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a session time out functionality implemented, in which user is presented with pop-up window (that your session is about to expire) in case no activity is done for 30-mins.

Need help on:

When this pop up opens up and let say user has locked his desktop and doesn't provide input. Then what I want is that - if user doesn't provide any input in 1 min then this pop-up will close and new popup will display that "Session is exprired"

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fairly easy to implement. Use the action listeners to detect the user action.

```
var userActionDetected = false;
var x = document.getElementById('yourID');
x.onclick = function (){
    // some more stuff you wanna do 
    userActionDetected = true;
};
setTimeout(
    function() {
        if(!userActionDetected){
            //close popups etc.
        }
    },
    60000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the popup has been created by `window.open`, then you can can just use `.close()` method like this:

```
var popup = window.open('some url', 'name_of_the_window');
setTimeout(function(){
    popup.close();
}, 60000);
```

here I am just closing popup after 1 minute without any checks of input, so you need to somehow check the input.

If the question is about how to check inputs, I can provide another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with plain `alert()` boxes, however there are at least two options:

1. Show an alert, with a note that the session will expire one minute after it showed up (maybe show the exact time it will expire). If the user clicks "OK" after the time is up, it will come back and say "Sorry, your session expired."
2. Custom alert boxes. This can be achieved very easily by having an element cover the screen and another show the information:

Example:

```
<div id="mask"><div id="alert">Your session will expire soon</div></div>
CSS:
#mask {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    /* fallback for browsers that don't support rgba() */
    background: #cccccc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
#alert {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px; /* half the width */
    top: 20%;
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
```

You can of course customise this further with buttons and so on. jQuery provides some libraries for this, but I made a fully-customisable box (unlimited buttons with custom text and callbacks) in just 40 lines of raw JavaScript. To each his own...

Comment: but who speaks about alert boxes? he speaks about popup windows

Comment: Well, a lot of users call `alert` boxes "popups" since, well, they pop up.

Comment: yes, maybe you are right, but I think you should ask that before posting an answer, because your answer can receive negative votes, because of inappropriateness